# Is there any way to define nullable fields by default without add nullable() in migration

Tags: laravel, migration, nullable

I want to set nullable fields in migration file without using ->nullable() from AppServiceProvider boot like:

```
 public function boot()
   {
      \Schema::defaultStringLength('191');
      \Schema::defaultNull('Yes');
   }
```

So, I can use in migration file like

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->string('password');
    $table->string('firstname');  // default nullable
    $table->string('lastname'); // default nullable
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

instead of,

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->string('password');
    $table->string('firstname')->nullable();
    $table->string('lastname')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Comment: The problem with your intention is if there's a way to default everything to null, then your password field with be null.

Comment: What Laravel version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Nullable is a constraint, you can try default(0) or default('') .

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->string('firstname')->default(0);  
        $table->string('lastname')->default(0);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

At least testing in Laravel 5.5.44 The `Blueprint` class is Macroable. Meaning you can add aditional functionalities to the class.

This means you can do something like this:

Add this to the `boot()` method of your `AppServiceProvider`

```
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
...

Blueprint::macro('nullableString', function(string $column, $length = null){ .              
    return $this->string($column, $length)->nullable();
});
```

Then you can use `nullableString()` in your migrations setup as follows:

```
...
$table->nullableString('firstname');  // default nullable
$table->nullableString('lastname'); // default nullable
...
```

Cheers!

> PS: I would be careful of excessively doing this automatically in many cases. Migrations are suppose to help you have a support documentation of your database Schema changes in a long run. But if you can manage it, why not?